# Certain phrases with numbers dont multiply by 2

Tags: java, string

Hi There so I have a project that basically finds all numbers i have and multiplies them by 2. I have it like 90% done but for the other 10% certain inputs don't work.

So my code finds all the numbers in a user input and multiplies them by 2.
(eg. 123woah becomes 246woah and woah888 becomes woah1776)
Can anyone find my error and explain to me what i need to do?

EDIT: For example a case that doesn't work is like 1abc1. The code doesn't work if the numbers are in different spots.

Thanks

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class MultiplyBy2
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int EXIT = 0;
            while(EXIT == 0)
            {
                Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("input?");
                String String1 = kbReader.nextLine();
                if(String1.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                {
                    break;
                }        
                else
                {
                    String String2 = String1;
                    String1 = String1.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(String1);
                    int j = i * 2 ;
                    String2 = String2.replaceAll("" + i, "" + j);
                    System.out.println(String2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For example one case that doesn't work is?

Comment: Please list non-working cases.

Comment: One obvious example: "2d2", where it'll parse "22" and then not be able to replace "22" with "44" anywhere...

Comment: Did you try to debug it and see what is happening?

Comment: So for `1abc1` what output would you want to have? `22abc`?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky It should be 2abc2

Comment: Then you have to rethink the whole logic of removing the alphabets and taking the resultant number because your current code will always make it 11 then and not like 1 and 1

Comment: While you're rethinking your logic as suggested by @Hanky웃Panky, you might want to rethink your loop - you never set EXIT. Also PLEASE name your variables with a lowercase letter at the start. e.g. `string1` instead of `String1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
String String1="1abc1";  // or woah888
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(String1);
while (m.find()) {
   Integer temp=Integer.parseInt(m.group());
   Integer temp2=temp*2;
   String1=String1.replaceFirst(temp.toString(),temp2.toString());
}
System.out.println(String1);
```

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/OKpMnF)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
    String text = "123.0114cc";
    String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}","");
    double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
    double newVal=numVal*2;
    text=text.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(numVal),String.valueOf(newVal));
    System.out.println(text);
```

Out put:

```
    246.0228cc
```

Comment: What about `1abc1`, `246woah` and the other test cases they provided